# Como centralizar opções de menu no bootstrap 3

Tags: css, bootstrap

Estou tentando deixar opções de um menu centralizado criado no bootstrap 3, já tentei alguns alternativas, mas nenhuma resolveu meu problema, tenho esse trecho de código:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-top">
<div class="container">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"> <i class="icon-menu-1"></i> </button>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
      <li><a href="index.php">INÍCIO</a></li>
      <li><a href="empresa.php">QUEM SOMOS</a></li>
      <li><a href="produtos.php">PRODUTOS E SERVIÇOS</a></li>
      <li><a href="livraria.php">LIVRARIA TÉCNICA</a></li>
      <li><a href="noticias.php">NOTÍCIAS</a></li>
      <li><a href="representantes.php">REPRESENTATES</a></li>
      <li><a href="contato.php">CONTATO</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

O meu css está assim:

```
.navbar-collapse {
  max-height: 340px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  overflow-x: visible;
  border-top: 1px solid transparent;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.nav {
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.navbar-nav {
  margin: 7.5px -15px;
}



.navbar-nav > li > a {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

Algumas alternativas que tentei:

```
.navbar-nav {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    > li {
      float: none;
      display: inline-block;
    }
```

E essa:

```
.navbar .navbar-nav {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
}

.navbar .navbar-collapse {
    text-align: center;
}
```

O que tenho hoje pode ser visto nessa imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você criou um arquivo separado do seu bootstrap.min para centralizar o menu?

Comment: Olá @RenatoLazaro, não cara, usei o código nativo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solução que você usou está correta, você só precisa acrescentar a propriedade `!important`

Simplesmente use o css:

```
.navbar .navbar-nav {
display: inline-block;
float: none !important;
}

.navbar .navbar-collapse {
text-align: center;
}
```

Veja se vai funcionar.

Comment: Olá @Wendell, valeu pela dica, me ajudou muito com esse problema.

Comment: @adventistapr Foi um prazer ajudar!

Answer (score 5):

Eu dei uma pequena mudada no css. O que achei de erro foi se seu código está igual ao que copiou para cá está faltando o fechamento da primeira div. O que você esqueceu foi centralizar a div principal com margin:0 auto, se você reparar você conseguiu centraliza-las na sua primeira tentativa, porém como a div principal não está centralizada acaba jogando para a esquerda como padrão.

```
.container {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

li {
    margin: 0.5%;
    background: #092962;
    width: 12.985714%;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Agradeço a ajuda @Ítalo Drago, realmente tinha postado sem fechar a div, muito obrigado.

Comment: Foi nada @adventistapr.

Answer (score 3):

Acredito que a melhor solução e também a mais simples, seria utilizar o flex-box!

```
#navbar {
  display: flex !important;
  justify-content: center !important;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Uma saída bem elegante para resolver sua questão é utilizar o poder incrível do flexbox. Abaixo segue um exemplo básico :

```css
nav ul {
   display: flex;
   width: 100%;
}

li {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" title="Home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="Blog">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="Work">Work</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="Resources">Resources</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="Meta">Meta</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score -1):

Basta usar:

```
.navbar .navbar-nav {
 display: inline-flex;
}
```